# Solve $\int_0^\infty \frac{p}{a^2-p^2}\frac{\sin(p r)}{(b^2+p^2)^2}dp$

Tags: definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I want to solve the PV of:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{p}{a^2-p^2}\frac{\sin(p r)}{(b^2+p^2)^2}dp$$

where $a, b, r$ are Reals.

I think, since the integral is symmetric, we can make $\int_0^\infty \rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty$. I think that we can apply the residuous theorem (note that we have to decompose the $\sin(pr)$ in imaginary exponentials). For +/- exponential we integrate in the below/above contour.

Comment: Of course your integral does not exist in usual sense unless $ar$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$. Are you interested in the Cauchy principal value of the integral?

Comment: yes im into the PV

Comment: Assuming $a, b, r > 0$ I got the result $$ PV \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{p}{a^2-p^2} \frac{\sin(pr)}{(b^2+p^2)^2} \, dp = \pi e^{-br} \frac{2b + r(a^2+b^2)}{4b(a^2+b^2)^2} - \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos(ar)}{(a^2+b^2)^2}. $$ Indeed, denoting the integrad by $f(p)$ we have $$ PV \int_{0}^{\infty} \, dp = i\pi \, \underset{z=ib}{\mathrm{Res}} \, f(p) + \frac{i\pi}{2} \underset{z=a}{\mathrm{Res}} \, f(p) + \frac{i\pi}{2} \underset{z=-a}{\mathrm{Res}} \, f(p). $$ All you have to do is to evaluate each residue.

Comment: but also exist the residue $z=-ib$, no? if i understand correctly, there are two poles in the below contour and two in the above. i have some cancellations in the  ib and -ib Res

Comment: That residue is not counted since I replaced the integrand to $$ \frac{p}{a^2-p^2} \frac{e^{irp}}{(p^2+b^2)^2}$$ and chose the upper semicircular contour with small semicircular indents at $p = \pm a$. With this integrand, you cannot choose the lower semicircular contour since the integral along the lower circular arc does not converge as the radius goes to infinity.

Comment: i have separate the integral in $$\frac{pe^{-ipr}}{(p+a)(p-a)(p+ib)^2(p-ib)^2}-\frac{pe^{ipr}}{(p+a)(p-a)(p+ib)^2(p-ib)^2}$$ the fisrt is evaluated in the below contron with the  two poles ($a-i\epsilon, -ib$) (-) and the second in the above contorn with the poles ($-a+i\epsilon, ib$)and a (+), no?

Comment: Separation will work, so I cannot tell anything unless I see your solution. Anyway, what do you mean by 'pole $a-i\epsilon$'?

Comment: I have redone the calculations and if u take into account the two exponentials of the $\sin(pr)$ (so two differents integrals in two differents contour) the result should be something like that. $$-\pi \frac{e^{-iar}}{(a^2+b^2)^2}$$